# How to use tkinter in Pycharm virtualenv?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I installed tkinter succesfully but I still get an error when I run my program in pycharm. It works fine if I run it from terminal.

I get this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I have a feeling I have to somehow tell my Pycharm virtual environment that it needs to include tkinter. This is not available in settings --> project interpreter.

I am on Linux Mint btw, and I use python3.7.

Comment: Have you tried File->Settings->Project Interpreter, then click '+' symbol and add tkinter.

Comment: Yeah it isn't in the list

Comment: Does that resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment, you need to find the Python location of the corresponding virtual environment, then use the `source` command to activate the virtual environment.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000639400-Activating-virtual-environment-in-Pycharm-python-console

[image]

```
# active virtualenv 
source virtualenv_path/bin/activate
```